# iPad App Stops Loading Local HTML Page - Cache Problem?

Tags: ipad

I created an html file that opens when the user taps a button in the iPad app. The html page resides on the iPad device. Unfortunately, if the user opens the html page immediately after opening the app, some of the images don't load, and the the display won't rotate when your turn the device 90 degrees. Also, the spinner that indicates that some kind of processing is happening keeps spinning for 3 minutes or more.

If the user exits the app and then reopens the app and opens the html page, it usually works fine.

If you open a remote version of the html page using the same iPad device outside the app, the html file loads and rotates perfectly all the time.

The html page includes about 70 small images, which take up a total of 221 KB.

I know there is an Apple bug that stops a page from loading after 6.5 mb has been downloaded, but the 221 KB is well under the 6.5 MB limit.

I think the problem might lie with how the app calls the html file or caches the data, but I am stumpted as to what specifically needs to be fixed.

Can anyone help?  Thanks very much.